# Opencart Url redirect

Tags: redirect, opencart

I made a custom registration module for Opencart,

my registration page has the following url:

www.mysite.com/index.php?route=account/customregister

while the default registration page url is:

www.mysite.com/index.php?route=account/register

I want to redirect users to my registration page (route=account/customregister) when users click on any link that points to the default registration module(route=account/register). I know I can edit the .htaccess file to make a redirect or a url rewriting but I want to do that by php. Do someone knows if there is some class/function or some kind of code I can put on my extension to automatically redirect users to the new url?

Thanks all in advance

P.s.
I cannot modify the core files and I would not edit the .htaccess.

Comment: Then You have Your hands tied well...You cannot modify the core files for what reason? What about using vQmod to dynamically modify the core files? And what is so bad with editing of .htaccess?

Comment: Core files will be overwritten every time Opencart will be updated with the new releases, my module might be installed on systems where vQmod is not installed (I was trying to avoid too many installation steps), and I prefer that users don't edit manually any file to make the things work. I was looking for a solution where the webmasters have only to merge the extension folder with the Opencart folder. To me the best and easiest solution was to edit the .htaccess file manually but I was trying to look for some more "creative" trick. And thank you in advance for all your suggestions

Comment: To be honest, the 'vQmod may not be installed' is one of those things that really isn't all that likely. I'd say 95% of all OC stores use vQmod

Comment: @Frank I am developing an OC extensions, too, and I always write them in the way of that vQmod is essential - no discussions. If somebody want my extension and do not have the vQmod installed, he has to do so. And this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be achieved with a vQmod pretty easily. You need to use a vQmod to edit the file `/catalog/controller/account/register.php` and put

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/customregister', '', 'SSL'));
```

just inside the `index()` method declaration (so use this as the search for the vQmod and use the `after` position)

Answer (score 5):

You can redirect from homepage to any product by adding this code in:

catalog/controller/common/home.php

```
$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=50', ''));
```

Where 50 is your product id. This is on Opencart 2.0.1.1. I did this because I only sell one product, hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware, but by default OC does a 302 redirect. If this is a perm thing, you may want to 301 it instead to pull juice from your homepage. `$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=50', '301'))`

Answer (score 1):

for redirection this may also work in opencart

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/customregister', '', 'SSL'));
```